Is there a way to enable Python on Vim installed via MacPorts?
I'm on macOS Monterey, most of my apps (including Vim and Neovim) are installed via Homebrew. Unfortunately, Homebrew just started stopped supporting Monterey, which means more packages will have to build from source instead of simply installing the binaries. So I switched to MacPorts
After installing Vim, I tried to edit a small file and got this:

Error detected while processing InsertCharPre Autocommands for
"*"..script
/Users/anta40/.vim/plugged/ultisnips/autoload/UltiSnips.vim: line
7: E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version: py3
import vim

Running vim --version, the result is...:
-python            +viminfo
+cmdline_info      +libcall           -python3

I also encountered similar error on neovim, fortunately installing py-neovim quickly solved the issue.
Wonder of there's a easy way for Vim...

Could you tell us what is the result of the :version command and in particular the Included patches: part and the python part of the :compilation part (the last part). It will help us to determine which version of Python you need to install?

Could you tell us what is the result of the following shell command: python -c "import sys;print(sys.version)"? It will help us to determine that is the version of python that is installed on your machine and the result of the following shell command: ls -l /usr/bin/python* it will help us to determine the version of Python available on your system.

The version of Vim has no Python support neither Python 2 support  -python nor Python 3 support -python3

Are you using macports or homebrew? The body doesn’t match the title.

@D.BenKnoble MacPorts. I've edited my post to make this clearer.

Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help you further? Otherwise maybe could you accept one of the solutions using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

Contrary to Neovim earlier version of Vim needs a particular version of Python that is determined at compilation (+python or +python/dyn for Python 2, +python3 or +python3/dyn for Python 3).
In recent version of Vim 9.1 (as of 20/09/2024) it is typically Python 3.12 for the binaries distributions.
In order for the py3 Vim command to work you need to install the version of Python 3 that match the one that Vim has been built against.
Remark: If you have a more recent version of Vim 9.1 that has the feature +python3/dyn-stable then Vim is able to use any recent version of Python 3 (>= 3.11).
Remark: Your situation seems more extreme. Your version of Vim seems not to have been compiled with Python support, neither Python 2 (-python and -python/dyn?) nor Python 3 (-python3 and -python3/dyn?).

Ouch... guess I have to built vim from source...

That is not completely true. You should use a vim compiled with python/dyn and then you may use other python version libraries (but it may still fail)

@ChristianBrabandt, I have updated the solution. Let me know if I'm closer to the truth.

No, If you have +python (without the dyn). The functionality the python feature will be built in. That means, Vim only starts, if you have the exact same python version available on your system. With python/dyn, the shared library is only loaded when you actually are calling some python stuff. It expects a default library (usually what was built with), but you can configure to use a different library using the 'pythonthreedll' and 'pythondll' option settings.

@ChristianBrabandt But the customer problem is with Ultisnip so it needs either +python or  +python/dyn. For +python/dyn he needs the exact same dll (the correct version of python). With +python/dyn-stable (that use the stable ABI) he can use any version above 3.8 (in the code Py_LIMITED_API=0x3080000 which means Python 3.8). Correct?

Correct, stable ABI should be prefered if possible

Sorry silly me. Digging at https://ports.macports.org/port/vim/details, it seems that Python support is already provided, but not enabled by default. You have to enable it, e.g sudo port install vim +big +lua +python311 +cscope. So far, my vim works fine.

Thanks for the feedback. I understand that the port command can 'install' a version of Vim compiled with Python 3.11 support. I'll investigate that :-)
